# asp Checkbox codebehind validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have a checkbox on my aspx page that loads from a list of strings (based on some other variables),
I only want the user to be able to select a constant number of these boxes; the current constant is 6. In my code behind I have been trying to validate this as I go; and if the 'selectedCount' equals my constant found in another class I will do something. The problem is that it is not recognizing the checks.

```
int selectedCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < checkbox.Items.Count; i++)
        {

            if (checkbox.Items[i].Selected == true)
            {
                selectedCount++;
            }
        }
```

My problem is that it loops through each item in the list, but even on the selected items it is returning false.  How to I properly check my selected/not selected bool in a case like this? since this obviously isnt doing the trick.

Comment: Can you post the ASPX of your CheckBox?

Comment: checkbox is checkboxlist?

Comment: Can you post the code where you are doing databinding? Note that if you are databinding OnLoad without checking IsPostback, the control will be re-bound on each postback, and by the time the above code runs, you will have lost its intended state.

Comment: could you show your Page_Load?

Comment: Awesome. It was the PostBack, I put the databind in side if(!IsPostback) and its working now. tricky bugger. Thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I can think of is you bind the CheckBoxList again in postback.

In order to prevent it, you want to use **IsPostBack**.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="CheckBoxList1" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("One", "1"));
        CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Two", "2"));
        CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Three", "3"));
        CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Four", "4"));
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int selectedCount = 0;
    var selectedText = new List<string>();
    foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            selectedCount++;
            selectedText.Add(item.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. This helped. I didn't catch that on the page load it was resetting itself. I threw it in a !Postback if and it worked great. thank you.